# Is `template<>` optional when specializing a class template using another class template?

Tags: c++, templates

I was trying to specialize a class template with another, as in the example below, and I noticed that this compiles and runs (at least on ideone, which is: gcc 4.3.4) whether the commented out line is commented out or not.

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename F>
struct foo{
  typedef F value_type;
};

template <typename G>
struct bar{};

//template<>  <- works if commented out or not
template <typename F>
struct bar<foo<F> >
{
  typename foo<F>::value_type val;
};

int main(void)
{
  typedef foo<int> F;
  typedef bar<F> B;
  B b;
  b.val = 10;
  std::cout << b.val << std::endl;
  return 0;
};
```

So my question is, is it really optional? I was under the impression that for such specialization the `template<>` line is required..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line should **not** be there.

When doing full specialization, there is `template<>` and it's mandatory. When doing partial specialization, you put the parameters of the partial specialization to those angle brackets and there is no additional `template` keyword.

So full specialization is:

```
template <>
struct bar<qyzzy>
```

and partial specialization is:

```
template <typename F>
struct bar<foo<F> >
```

Each has exactly one `template` keyword and two pairs of angle brackets.

Comment: I searched through the bugs database, and this appears to have been a problem in the past (i.e. accepting the extra `template<>`), I guess all the situations were fixed but the above may have somehow been missed.

Comment: Where you say "explicit" specialization, you refer to what's called "full" specialization.

Comment: @sbi: Ok, changed to "full specialization" (both are explicit).

Comment: @JanHudec: Yes, but partial specializations are explicit, too.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
template<>
template <typename F>
struct bar<foo<F> >;
```

should be a syntax error, me thinks.

Comment: ..interesting.. even 4.5.1 (latest I have access to) quite happily accepts the above...

Comment: @Nim: What if you write yet *another* template<>. Does it start complaining or eats it up?

Comment: @Armen, now it complains about too many template-parameters-lists

Comment: @Nim: Are you sure all your code isn't within another template?

Comment: @Nim: Silly question, of course you are... I just thought better of gcc :)

Comment: @Armen, there are too many bugs in the database related to templates and specialization, I could not find a perfect match, so I've submitted one... will be interesting to see if it is indeed known...

Answer (score 1):

The line with `template <>` should be commented out. Otherwise it should be an error. Bar is a namespace-level template, so in order to specialize it you just write

```
template <parameters if any>
class bar <arguments>
{
};
```

I have no idea why gcc accepts when you uncomment the line. I can assure you it most certainly should ***not***